# apply datatables.js style to table loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

```
$(document).on('click', '.manage', function (event)
{
    var userid = $(this).data('userid');


    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'html',
        url:"../user/ajax/doclist.php",
        async:true,
        data:{userid:userid,task:'view'},
        success:function(html)
        {   

            $('.doclistdiv').html(html);
        },
        error:function(request,errorType,errorMessage) 
        {
            alert ('error - '+errorType+'with message - '+errorMessage);
        },
        complete:function(html)
        {   
        }
    });



});
```

as above code shown i'm loading ajax data(as a html) to my page.
in among those data i have table.i want to after loading that table convert to table as table in datatable.js(www.datatables.net/)

i think because data come as a html there server side processing is not working

Comment: have you tried set create the plugin using HTML(DOM) as source  ?http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your success section:

```
var root = $('.doclistdiv');
root.html(html);
root.find('table').dataTable();
```